Ninject - InRequestScope for non-web context with pooling of instances
I am working on a .NET 8 non web project where I am using Ninject for dependency injection. One part of the app involves parsing a file. I have a set of classes that achieve that but they can only be used for one parsing operation at a time. This means each time I want to parse a file I need to get a fresh parser instance. I want to solve this using Ninject.
However, I want that the parser instance and its dependencies are coming from a pool and are returned to this pool when they are disposed(or in some other way). It shouldn't come to the point that any of the resolved instances will be garbage collected.
This is essentially like InRequestScope with a OnDeactivation handler that would return the instance to the pool. Only InRequestScope doesn't work outside of web project contexts.
Is there anything in Ninject or its extensions that can achieve exactly this or at least aid with it? I looked at Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope but I didn't seem to find a way to achieve my goal. I also experimented with InScope but couldn't get it to work. I also looked at this stackoverflow thread but it seems to complex for what I would consider a rather common thing.
